# Don't have Mnemonic seed from https://moneroaddress.org/ --- Can I still access funds that I sent to offline wallet?

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, bittrex

***update:*
I realize what I did. I went and created an offline wallet on https://moneroaddress.org/ but didn't write down the info. Noob mistake I suppose. 
If anyone can help me find a way to still access my funds to my wallet please let me know. I have the block explorer info on the withdraw I did on Bittrex**

I'm trying to catch up here and am pretty new but have done a lot of homework. However, I withdrew funds from Bittrex and had to generate a monero wallet in order to do so. I did this and have the address and the withdraw info from Bittrex. I don't believe I did it on mymonero.

I am downloading the Monero GUI and am hoping I can get my funds transferred over from the wallet I created on Bittrex.

Bittrex sent me the Block Explorer info and it shows an https:// monderoblocks.info/search/ (with the transaction ID following).

This shows the private and public keys (says key image and public key).

Can I use this info to bring the funds into the Monero GUI I downloaded?

Basically I have a monero wallet I generated quickly to pull out funds from Bittrex. I have the address to that wallet and the key image and the public key from the block exporer but that's all I have. Can I get these funds into my new wallet I generated off the monero GUI?

The help is very much appreciated. I'm spending so much time trying to figure this out.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In order to access the monero on a particular account, you need the secret keys for that account. The mnemonic seed is a representation of those using words. So if you did not keep the mnemonic seed, nor the secret keys, that monero is lost forever.

Now, there's a much better chance that the browser might have saved that page to disk, or that it might be written to swap, but that's still probably out of luck. You could maybe grep the swap partition for "Keep it secure!", which is the bit of text just before the seed on that page. Quite the long shot though.

Comment: I tried to recover but unsuccessfully. Tough way to lose around $400 bucks. At least it was only some of my fantasy football winnings ;-) Next time I'll be more careful.